# ValueError in python: both int and float is not working

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnLP.jpg)

```
W = int(input())
words = input().split()
# code below
page_width=int(input())
words=[None]
for W in input().split():
    words.append(w)
S=[0]*len(words)
pages=[0]*len(words)

for i in range(1,len(words)):
    curr_width=0
    min_penalty = len(words)*(page_width**3)
    j=word_break=i
    while j > 0:
        curr_width += len(words[j]) + 1
        curr_penalty = S[j-1]+(page_width-curr_width+1)**3
        if curr_width-1<= page_width:
            if min_penalty > curr_penalty:
                min_penalty=curr_penalty
                word_break=j
        else:
            break
        j=j-1
    S[i]=min_penalty
    pages[i]=word_break

print(S[len(words)-1])
```

error when I put int:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

error when I put a float:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

input:12

> ape eats apple cider a lot.

why is it happening? I know that ValueError occurs, but I have no idea why it happens at the both situations.

```
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'py3_run' failed
make: *** [py3_run] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.out", line 4, in <module>
    page_width=float(input())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

Makefile:6: recipe for target 'py3_run' failed
make: *** [py3_run] Error 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.out", line 4, in <module>
    page_width=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Please post the full error. You have 3 `input`s there. Give the exact input you give to each one

Comment: It's hard to tell what's supposed to happen here. Try changing your `input()` calls to just hard-coded strings and numbers and make things work like that first.

Comment: or I will edit it right now

Comment: It seems like your inputs are empty...

Answer (score 0):

See, when you take  input from the first line, it reads the whole line, as there are strings in the same line it cant convert them into int. I hope this clears your doubt.
Try this:

```
d=input().split()
W=int(d[0])
words=d[1:]
```

Comment: Can u please give me advice about how to fix it?

Comment: Error is at line 6: loop variable is 'W' but you are using w inside the loop

Comment: Please forgive me for the last question,  d=input().split()
W=int(d[0])
words=d[1:]
page_width=int(input())
for W in input().split():
 words.append(W)
S=[0]*len(words)
pages=[0]*len(words)... is this right code?

Comment: but the same error is coming out. I posted a picture, can you check it, please?

Comment: bro you are not at all providing input to page_width, give the respective inputs and try